# Publish/subscribe not working - how to debug?

Tags: meteor, iron-router, publish-subscribe

I am trying to switch my app from autopublish to publish/subsribe. After trying to set publish/subscribe up or my first collection, none of my items from the collection are being displayed anymore, and I am at a loss at what might be going wrong.

Can someone spot a mistake in my code below or give any hints as to how to debug this type of problem?

**client/routes.js**

```
Router.route('/slug', {
  name: 'route.name',
  title: 'My Page',
  template: 'TemplateName',
  subscriptions: function() {
    this.subscribe('myPublication');
  },
  action: function() {
    this.render();
  }
});
```

**server/lib/collectionLib.js**

```
...
Meteor.publish('myPublication', function() {
  return MyCollection.find();
});
```

**client/myCollection/view/mycollection-list.html**

```
...
{{#each myCollection}}
    ...
{{/each}}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the exposure of the collection to the template. See answer provided here: https://forums.meteor.com/t/publish-subscribe-not-working-how-to-debug/13127/6?u=codejak

Answer (score 0):

Oh I see now, unless you are doing `MyCollection.find()` in your template helper you need to do it in the route:

```
data: function () {
  return MyCollection.find({}).fetch();
}
```

Comment: That does not solve my problem, unfortunately. I was following the documentation for Iron Router when writing my code, where no return is being used: http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#route-specific-options

Comment: @codejak - actually that should solve your problem, you need a template helper or IR's data method to access the data in your template.